# Nav being pushed down inside fixed div

Tags: html, css

I want the links to be also `vertical-aligned: middle;` next to the `<h1>`element.
But this isn't possible, because the nav is being pushed down for some reason.
I've checked it and there is no margin or padding.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/

```
<div class="fixed">
  <h1>
  Title
  </h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

.fixed
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}

h1
{
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;

  color:white;
}

nav
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;

    top:0;
    right:0;

    > ul
    {
        height:auto;

        > li
        {
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 0 12px;
            text-align:center;
            line-height: inherit;
            display:inline-block;


            &:not(:last-child)
            {
                margin-right:0;
            }

            button
            {
              padding: 0;

              &:hover
              {
                background-color: inherit;
                border:none;
              }
            }

            a
            {
                line-height: 50px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you have made both the nav and h1 into inline-block elements, you need to apply the same vertical-align to them to make them line up: https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/4/ or if you want the li centered too: https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/13/

Comment: check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/26/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the nav height: 100px; then whatever you want to vertical align give it the line-height: 100px;

https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/14/

Otherwise I would just change your whole structure and use flexbox, much cleaner and easier check it out:

```
.fixed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;

  li {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dak3up0m/23/

Answer (score 1):

I think a very elegant solution is this one using flexbox. In general, when you're trying to have several elements vertically centered, this is the easiest and best performance way. Futhermore, The code is cleaner.

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DsEsteban/dak3up0m/25/)

```
.fixed
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  display:flex;
}

h1
{
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0 10px;
  color:white;
}

nav
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-around;
    background-color:green;

    top:0;
    right:0;

    > ul
    {
        height:auto;
        padding: 0px 40px;
        > li
        {
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 0 12px;
            text-align:center;
            line-height: inherit;
            display:inline-block;


            &:not(:last-child)
            {
                margin-right:0;
            }

            button
            {
              padding: 0;

              &:hover
              {
                background-color: inherit;
                border:none;
              }
            }

            a
            {
                line-height: 50px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```